# Azure AAD user login silently for Datalake U-SQL job submit

Tags: authentication, active-directory, jobs, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have tried the sample from https://github.com/blumu/azure-content/blob/master/articles/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-get-started-net-sdk.md
In the Above sample, the user has logged in using the interactive popup but I want login silently. Is there any other way to do it?

```
 public static ServiceClientCredentials AuthenticateAzure(
    string domainName,
    string nativeClientAppCLIENTID)
{
    // User login via interactive popup
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
    // Use the client ID of an existing AAD "Native Client" application.
    var activeDirectoryClientSettings = ActiveDirectoryClientSettings.UsePromptOnly(nativeClientAppCLIENTID, new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"));
    return UserTokenProvider.LoginWithPromptAsync(domainName, activeDirectoryClientSettings).Result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as a matter of fact, there sure is a way of doing this. I solved this in a project recently like this. The whole magic lies in the **LoginSilentAsync** function. Details can be found on this Microsoft post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk

```
 private ServiceClientCredentials Authenticate(string _adlsWebClientId, string _adlsClientSecret, string _adlsDomain)
    {               
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_adlsWebClientId, _adlsClientSecret);

        return ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(_adlsDomain, clientCredential).Result;

    }
```

I invoked the **Authenticate()** function in the constructor of the class; and then went on to use it like this:

```
 ServiceClientCredentials _creds = Authenticate(... ... ...);
 string _subscriptionId = "XXXXXXXXX";
// Create client objects and set the subscription ID
 DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient _adlsClient = new  DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient(_creds) { SubscriptionId = _subscriptionId };
 DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient _adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(_creds);
```

Let me know if that's what you were asking for